Regex Match with the last pattern
Suppose I have a .txt file that needs to split using regex, and. So far, I've managed to split using my Regex Pattern.
This is my .txt file:
HMT940040324
SUBH2002078568
2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2002078568:20:20210420182417
2002078568:25:2002078568
2002078568:28C:00075
2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568-}
SUBF2002078568
SUBH2003001298
2003001298{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2003001298:20:20210420182417
2003001298:25:2003001298
2003001298:28C:00075
2003001298:60F:C210420IDR111520964,38
2003001298:62F:C210420IDR111520964,38
2003001298-}
SUBF2003001298
FMT9400000004

When I applied my regex pattern :
(?<=SUBH2002078568)[\s\S]+(?=SUBF2002078568)

I've managed to get my desired result:
2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2002078568:20:20210420182417
2002078568:25:2002078568
2002078568:28C:00075
2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568-}

Which is only extracted between SUBH2002078568 and SUBF2002078568
But, when the account appeared in another line i.e :
HMT940040324
SUBH2002078568
2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2002078568:20:20210420182417
2002078568:25:2002078568
2002078568:28C:00075
2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568-}
SUBF2002078568
SUBH2003001298
2003001298{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2003001298:20:20210420182417
2003001298:25:2003001298
2003001298:28C:00075
2003001298:60F:C210420IDR111520964,38
2003001298:62F:C210420IDR111520964,38
2003001298-}
SUBF2003001298
SUBH2002078568 // *Added this account from the top*
2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2002078568:20:20210420182417
2002078568:25:2002078568
2002078568:28C:00075
2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568-}
SUBF2002078568- // End
FMT9400000004

The result is messy like this :
2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2002078568:20:20210420182417
2002078568:25:2002078568
2002078568:28C:00075
2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568-}
SUBF2002078568
SUBH2003001298
2003001298{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2003001298:20:20210420182417
2003001298:25:2003001298
2003001298:28C:00075
2003001298:60F:C210420IDR111520964,38
2003001298:62F:C210420IDR111520964,38
2003001298-}
SUBF2003001298
SUBH2002078568
2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
2002078568:20:20210420182417
2002078568:25:2002078568
2002078568:28C:00075
2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
2002078568-}

What should I change my pattern so the result would be :
{ 
 2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
 2002078568:20:20210420182417
 2002078568:25:2002078568
 2002078568:28C:00075
 2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
 2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
 2002078568-}
},
{
 2002078568{1:F01BANK MBI}{2:I940MAP}{4:
 2002078568:20:20210420182417
 2002078568:25:2002078568
 2002078568:28C:00075
 2002078568:60F:D210420IDR0,
 2002078568:62F:D210420IDR0,
 2002078568-}
}

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

I guess this is a swift format for banking? Though the data looks old, but I hope you didn't post real data.

@PekoMiko Yea for banking and its dummy tho so, no worries.

It's because your regex,
(?<=SUBH2002078568)[\s\S]+(?=SUBF2002078568)

uses +, which tries to match as long as possible ("greedy operator"). Instead, you can use:
(?<=SUBH2002078568)[\s\S]+?(?=SUBF2002078568)

I added a ? after +, ? specifies it to match as short as possible (lazy operator).

Thanks for the response. That's amazing! I didn't know that could works. Question, how do I get the bottom account?

Depends on how you do match, but methods like Regex.Matches() returns a collection of results like [top account, bottom account], so you can iterate through that collection and get all results.

There's no difference between + and {1,}.

Thanks for the tip! Changed it to use +.
